# How does macOS locate applications by bundle identifier?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

`absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier` and `URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier` are API calls that take in a bundle identifier and return the path to the application that's declared that identifier. How does this work?

- Is there a cache?

  - Where is it located?
  - What format is it in?
  - What updates this cache?
  - Can I query this cache directly from the command line?
- What happens if there's multiple bundles with same identifier, such as multiple versions of the same app or two apps that have an id collision?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services?language=objc). This part of macOS maintains the database of applications, and as you'll read in the documentation is used by the Finder itself. HTH

Comment: Thanks CRD. Do you know how it works under the hood though? Is there a long running daemon that watches for file events? Where does it save what it discovers?